# Is there a more efficient way to detect UIScrollView offset?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I made an infinite scrolling calendar in a `UIScrollView`, where each may can contain up to eight subviews. The function I'm calling inside `scrollViewDidScroll()` looks like this (simplified):

```
func addAndRemoveRow(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollViewZeroOffsetY < -heightOfDay/2 {  // Going back in time.
        createRowAtBottom()
        removeRowAtTop()
    } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollViewZeroOffsetY > heightOfDay/2 {  // Going forward in time.
        createRowAtTop()
        removeRowAtBottom()
    }
}
```

Functionally, this works perfectly, and in the mode where each row contains a single day, it runs smoothly even on my iPhone 5 (both modes run fluidly on the simulator). However, in the mode where each row contains a week, it's pretty choppy.

It seems like overkill to call `addAndRemoveRow()` every time the scrollview is moved even a pixel. Is there a way to call it less frequently?

(Alternatively, is there a more optimized way of doing this? I tried using a `UICollectionView` and it doesn't run any more smoothly.)

[image: mockup]

Comment: I'd be curious why a collection view didn't help, because from your code it seems that dequeuing cells would yield a significant amount of performance

Comment: There were still so many subviews to remove each time a cell was dequeued, and to add each time a cell was requeued, that the collection view only saved the creation/destruction cost of 7 views (out of around 63 total views created/destroyed during each update). Or am I misunderstanding how to use UICollectionView?

Comment: Naftali, If you have a screen shot of what your view looks like it might be easier to diagnose how you should use a collectionView.  Really you shouldn't be adding/removing subviews when using a collectionView, just dequeuing cells.
You may need to break up your cells differently or use multiple collectionViews.

Comment: When I was new to swift I also tried to use a scrollview as a collectionview. Using the didScroll function to create/update content. This doesn't work at all. I even tried letting the update functions run on a different thread, still choppy. Big advantage of a collection view is that you can use sections. Putting your data in a nested array (or related table in Core Data) is good way to keep it all structured. Because you say "creation/destruction" i am also thinking you are not reusing cells. Collection views reuse cells and update their content. They do not need to be created/destroyed.

Comment: @Alex I've added a mockup of the worst-case scenario - each gray box is a subview of a cell item. I was simply letting cells automatically dequeue, but the cell's subviews persisted (just building new subviews on top of old ones), so I had to manually remove them each time. Obviously I'm misunderstanding how to dequeue and reuse cells - if that doesn't happen automatically, how do I manually do it?

Comment: @RMenke How did you know I was new to Swift? ;) Good to know there's a consensus that I'm doing it inefficiently - I guess UICollectionView is the way to go. See my comment to Alex if you have any further advice. (I'm holding all my data in a dictionary, btw.)

Comment: @NaftaliBeder With infinite do you mean load in demand or like a circular way?

Comment: @VictorSigler Not circular. It should have a bottom end (the present day/week), but ideally extend infinitely upwards into the past.

Comment: @NaftaliBeder If your cells can create any subviews that they need the first time that they are loaded i.e. in `awakeFromNib` or add them in your xib (if your using one) you can then hide/show them or configure any of the subviews(without adding or removing) each time the cell gets dequeued based on the information you have for that cell.  Ideally I would avoid creating and removing subviews on each dequeue.  
Alternative approach would be to have different cells for different configurations but since these are all similar that seems like overkill.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your help, one more question for clarification. If I have, say, 4,000 cells, and I create all their subviews on load, do the subviews get automatically dequeued along with their parent cell (so only the subviews of the onscreen cells are in memory)?

Comment: If you have 4,000 cells, your collection view will only create around 100 (how many can fit on screen) of them.  so you will have 100 cells in memory, each of those cells will have your 9 subviews in them so those will also be in memory.  So you will have around 900 views in memory, but this still shouldn't give you a problem.  If it does there are some interesting things you can do to get around having the 9 subviews in each cell including using a custom path or masks, but you shouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: @Alex Perfect, thanks for your help. I think I asked the wrong question in the beginning, so I'm not sure whether to accept your answer, but I appreciate it either way.

Answer (score 1):

I would be curious as to why a UICollectionView didn't help.  I have had collectionView's with 100's of cells on the screen at the same time and it has run very smoothly even on 5's.

If you still have your implementation of the collectionView, some things I would check to see if it can help your performance would be:

1: Make sure that you are reusing cells and that your datasource isn't changing dynamically unless it needs too.  Also make sure that if you are adding more subviews to a cell that it is done in `awakeFromNib` instead of when you configure it and reuse your changes if possible.

2: if there is a lag on startup, use estimated size assuming your using iOS8+ and a flow layout `@property (nonatomic) CGSize estimatedItemSize NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);`

3: If you'r not using a flow layout make sure you are only returning the correct number of layout attributes for `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect;`  You should only have to return the attributes for whatever is in the rect.

4: Try not invalidating the layout on bounds change to see if it helps performance.

If you are doing more dynamic things with the view this is a good read: http://www.raizlabs.com/2013/10/animating-items-uicollectionview-2/